# Help with HTML Button and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

I am working on a project our website designer gave us this code for users to pick their order

```
 <img src="images/product001.png" alt="" />
 <h1>Espresso Roast Pods</h1>
 <span>Php 999.99</span>
<button>Order</button>
```

all we need to do is add a php code to it when a user clicks the button it will send the order to the database, do you have any idea how we are going to do it?  THanks in advance

Comment: `do you have any idea how we are going to do it?` yes, through *programming.* It's a long process that requires some expertise, and it will be more than "a code". Chances are it will take more time than the website designer took to create the design.

Comment: Well, PHP should help, thought.

Comment: It seems that you'd better learn some web development knowledge first.

Comment: @Ernestas Stankevičius I just lol'd. Thanks. :]

Comment: I know through PHP but specifically do I need to use form? and yes I'll use it with php

Comment: You should probably think about using some sort of content management system like WordPress and use their e-commerce plugin.  That is probably the fastest and easiest of going about this without much programming knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you need to make that there button do something. It has no type attached to it, nor a name. You need both to make the magic happen.

THEN in your PHP script you add a conditional to check if the button in question was what triggered the form processing. For instance, if you named the button `btnOrderExpresso`, your conditional would look like this:

```
if( isset( $_POST['btnOrderExpresso'] ) ) {
    # magic here
}
```

Comment: that's something I have in mind but how would I name the button? any idea?

Comment: Uh, using the "name" attribute.

Comment: I suggest you start here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/elements-form

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work

Comment: tried this but it didn't work

<img src="images/product001.png" alt="" />
 <h1>Espresso Roast Pods</h1>
 <span>Php 999.99</span>
<button name="Expresso" type=" { button | reset | submit } " value="value">Order</button>

Comment: You have to choose a specific type, i.e. type="button". You need to actually read the reference, not just copy the first thing that looks like code. There will not be a "value" attribute on a `<button>` element.